# Using notepad++ command line commands

Tags: command-line, notepad++

I am trying to use the `-l` parameter in a notepad++ command line to open a file and have the highlighting be set to highlight for C++.

I typed in the command:

```
 notepad++ -lC++ file.cpp
```

For some reason this does not work.

Notepad++ is already added to the PATH.

Comment: What is it doing when that command is entered? For instance is the error: "'notepad++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."?

Comment: there is no error that the program returns, it just doesnt set the syntax highlighting to C++ format. The file opens with no highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language names you see in the menus are not the names you need to use.  You can see a list of all the languages in the `langs.xml` file in your Notepad++ data directory, which is usually:

```
%APPDATA%\Notepad++\langs.xml
```

In that file you will see the `name` property for C++ files is actually `cpp`.

```
notepad++ -lcpp file.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @heavyd for your answer. I used this code to open a command line compiling environment and open a new `.cpp` file in notepad++ with syntax highlighting.

Here is how I used it:

```
@echo off
set /p newprogram="Enter Program Name:"


start cmd /C "cd C:\source\ && notepad++ -lcpp %newprogram%.cpp"
start cmd /K "E:\VisualStudio\VC\vcvarsall.bat && cd C:\source\"

exit
```